# Wrong to insert a record into a table by SQLite in an android project

Tags: android, sqlite, insert

I create a table like this:

```
DB_CREATE = "create table " + DB_TABLE + " (" + 
"id" + " integer, " + 
 "title" + " text, " + "author" + " text, " + 
 "image" + " text, " +   "time" + " text, " +
 "detail" + " text);";

 _db.execSQL(DB_CREATE);
```

which _db is reference to SQLiteDatabase.  I invoke the method insert() as follows:

```
ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
    if(object instanceof NewsBean) {
        newValues.put("id", ((NewsBean) object).getId());
        newValues.put("title", ((NewsBean) object).getTitle());
        newValues.put("author", ((NewsBean) object).getAuthor());
        newValues.put("image", ((NewsBean) object).getImage());
        newValues.put("time", ((NewsBean) object).getTime());
        newValues.put("detail", ((NewsBean) object).getDetail());

        return db.insert(DB_TABLE, null, newValues);
```

}

The problem is that the elements in newValues do not list as the table colomns. How to solve it? I do not want to change the table.

Comment: Uninstall your app and reinstall. If you haven't upgraded the DB, this will fix it. Conversely, you could try a database upgrade to reinstantiate the table. This is of course assuming that your app was working before you added the database feature and that you are calling it. Could you post you stack trace?

Comment: What do you mean by do not list as the table columns? Do you mean the order?

Comment: Yes, the order is not like as the table's.

Comment: Thanks @AedonEtLIRA. I do what you tell, the errors about insert method disappear. However, another problem occure. I am sorry that I am not able to post the stack trace. How?

Answer (score 3):

The "id" column is defined to be autoincremented. So you must not put a value for the "id" column into ContentValues.

Comment: I do not implements a conent provider, the "id" colunm is defined by myself, not be autoincreamented.

Comment: @Androidist, if it is not to be autoincremented, then why is DB_CREATE defined as "integer primary key autoincrement, "?

Comment: ,I am sorry that it is my mistake to define "id" as "integer primary key autoincrement."